# Windows NT history: Was it possible to upgrade in-place from OS/2 to Windows NT 3.1?

Tags: windows, history, os2

Was it possible to upgrade in-place from OS/2 1.2 or 1.3 on a HPFS volume to Windows NT 3.1?

I know NT 3.1 supported booting from HPFS and had an OS/2 subsystem to run OS/2 1.x programs. NT was also meant to be a replacement for OS/2 originally. But I wonder whether NT 3.1 would detect an existing OS/2 1.x installation and offer to install over it, allowing installed programs to function in NT and whether NT allowed for a dual-boot option like it did for MS-DOS on a FAT drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes it is possible!

With OS/2 1.x on HPFS NT 3.1 will install alongside it and allow you to dual boot both. I have not tried running OS/2 programs on NT but I imagine it will work.

What's interesting is that with HPFS specifically NT warns that with OS/2 2.0 or later, booting OS/2 will no longer be possible. Sure enough I tried this with 2.1 and it creates a dual boot entry for OS/2 but it doesn't boot. (Files are kept). With a FAT filesystem there is no such warning and NT can dual boot with OS/2 2.x. I don't know what changed in 2.0 and only on HPFS!

13 years later, I'm sure you're still waiting for this answer.

Comment: Related: https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26095

Comment: “13 years later, I'm sure you're still waiting for this answer.” I am sure the original poster doesn’t care at this point, but I just rewarded you a 50 point bounty because it is a good, late answer. Nice work!

Comment: I still find it interesting. Thanks!